# Xamarin Forms DatePicker and TimeTicker text color for android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am unable to set the text color for the TimePicker and DatePicker on Android. Also, when I set the background color of the dialog to a dark color the clock turns white (see pick).
What I managed to achieved was adding a style in the styles.xml to change the textColor. However, I need to be able to change the textColor in the renderer (setting the textColor in Xaml did not work for this). Basically, in the clock dialog, I need to change the clock color even to a static gray is fine, the Set Time dialog however, I need to be able to switch the text from dark to light and vice versa.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To modify the color of the data picker, you can try to modify the styles.xml as follows.

```
 <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>
 </style>
    
 <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
  <!--header background-->
  <item name="colorAccent">#009933</item>
  <!--header textcolor-->
  <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ff9900</item>
  <!--body background-->
  <item name="android:windowBackground">#000099</item>
  <!--selected day-->
  <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff8000</item>
  <!--days of the month-->
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffff00</item>
  <!--days of the week-->
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff0066</item>
  <!--cancel&ok-->
  <item name="android:textColor">#00ffff</item>
 </style>
```

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/488323/xamarinforms-datepicker-dialogue-color-customizati.html

Comment: I've already mentioned the styles.xml in my post. I need to switch them.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two different styles which represent `Light` and `Dark` mode in `Styles.xml`

```cs
<style name="DarkTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.
    -->
</style>


<style name="LightTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.
    -->
</style>
```

Choose corresponding style with dark/light mode in `MainActivity.cs`.

```cs
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            Configuration config = Resources.Configuration;
            var ThemeMode = config.UiMode == (UiMode.NightYes | UiMode.TypeNormal);
            if (ThemeMode) SetTheme(Resource.Style.DarkTheme);
            else SetTheme(Resource.Style.LightTheme);
        }
}
```

However, in this way you need to restart the app every time while switching the mode .